# Rewrite SortedMap with streams Java

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have this code:

```
 SortedMap<String, Double> starsPerActivity = new TreeMap<>();
        for(Product p : products.values()) {
            for(Rating r : ratings) {
                if(r.getProductName() == p.getName()) {
                    starsPerActivity.put(p.getActivityName(), this.getStarsOfProduct(p.getName()));
                }
            }
        }
        return starsPerActivity;
```

And I want to rewrite this piece of code with streams.
I tried, but I don't know how.

> The method starsPerActivity() returns a map that associates a name of the activity to the average number of stars for the products belonging to that activity, with the activity names sorted alphabetically. Activities whose products have not been rated should not appear in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [third `Collectors.toMap` overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
public static <T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>>
Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                         Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                         BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                         Supplier<M> mapFactory)
```

Which allows you to define what map implementation you'd like to use:

```
SortedMap<String, Double> starsPerActivity = products.values().stream()
     .filter(p -> ratings.stream()
         .anyMatch(r -> r.getProductName().equals(p.getName())))
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         Product::getActivityName, 
         p -> getStarsOfProduct(p.getName()), 
         Double::max, TreeMap::new
     ));
```

Also I noticed that you used `r.getProductName() == p.getName()` in your `if` statement, which is probably applied to `String`s. This is discouraged, see: [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Note that this implementation picks the rating with the highest value. You can change this behaviour by replacing `Double::max` with the logic you like. If you want the same behaviour you currently have then you could use this, which is close enough: `(a, b) -> b` which simply picks the latest put value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedMap<String, Double> starsPerActivity = new TreeMap<>();
        products.values().forEach(p -> ratings.stream().filter(r -> r.getProductName().equals(p.getName()))
                .forEachOrdered(r -> starsPerActivity.put(p.getActivityName(), this.getStarsOfProduct(p.getName()))));
```